# How to use rsync to restore folder time meta-data

Tags: directory, rsync, file-metadata

A large amount of data was transferred from one NAS to a new NAS via windows explorer because of speed considerations.   An attempt to use rsync was half-successful and restored the dates of files, but not the folders.

```
rsync -ax --size-only --progress root@192.168.8.109:/shares/Public/Drivers /shares/Public
```

I was advised that adding -v to the statement and [this link would help explain why it was not changed.](http://andreafrancia.it/2010/03/understanding-the-output-of-rsync-itemize-changes.html)  My attempt to decode was not successful.

The request is for a command line example (similar to above) that will sync the files and folder meta-data.   Looking forward to clever responses and a good narrative.

Comment: You ask already a question. Please consider clarify and comment in it: http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/306987/will-rsync-restore-original-file-metadata

Comment: @RomeoNinov: Thank you for reviewing my question. I have modified parent question per your request.  If you or anyone else understands the answer to this question and posts it to the parent question I will delete this post.